# How to open a post route with Spring security and JWT?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I had configured the security of my application and I tried to implement only the user that have the role 'CHEF' can add a new data on a especific post method.

I set the csrf disable and before make the filter a enable it. But it doens't work.

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceCustom userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/receitas/add").hasAnyRole("CHEF")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/receitas/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

The Auth entrypoint:

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

And this is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/receitas")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public class ReceitaController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ReceitaService receitaService;

    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listar() {

        List<Receita> receitas = receitaService.findAll();

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Receita>>(receitas, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/chef")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('CHEF')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> teste() {

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Chef autorizado", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('CHEF')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> salvar(@RequestBody CreateReceitaDTO receita) {
        System.out.println("tentando fazer " + receita.getName());

        try {
            Receita newReceita = receitaService.createReceita(receita);

            return new ResponseEntity<Receita>(newReceita, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionResponse exception = new ExceptionResponse(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(exception, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

And my JWt utils class:

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${teles.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${teles.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    @Value("${teles.app.jwtCookieName}")
    private String jwtCookie;

    public String getJwtFromCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, jwtCookie);
        if (cookie != null) {
            return cookie.getValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ResponseCookie generateJwtCookie(UserDetailsCustom userPrincipal) {
        String jwt = generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, jwt).path("/api").maxAge(24 * 60 * 60).httpOnly(true)
                .build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public ResponseCookie getCleanJwtCookie() {
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, null).path("/api").build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    private Key key() {
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret));
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build().parse(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        try {
            return Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(username)
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                    .signWith(key(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                    .compact();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while generation token", e);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to do the POST method the message: "Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource". But when I do the GET with the same PreAuthorize I got the status 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't get this error message in GET request to the same request mapping is in requestMachers that you have, check attached screenshot, but for others endpoints you don't have any roles restriction.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but does not work a can't do the post using it and using csrf

Comment: disable cors too and retry, tell me it if was helpful

Comment: http.cors(cors -> cors.disable())

Comment: It doens't work as well

Comment: one questions to have more details, in your jwt token do you have any fields that represent user roles ?

Comment: actually not. but I edited the post and now you can see my jwt class

Comment: i mean, payload of token that you get from cookies have a field with user authorities ?

Comment: If doesn't have, this is your problem i think

Comment: In your method `generateTokenFromUsername` you don't do it with authorities

Comment: I found the problem and it was just that the body was wrong. Sorry and thank u s2

Comment: good,  body do you mean jwt payload ?